# ode45 system second order

Tags: system, ode, differential-equations

i have write this program but it's not working

```
function xprime = exh(t,z)
xprime = [z(2);
          30*z(3) - 40*z(1); 
          z(4);
          30*z(1)+30*z(5)-60*z(3);
          z(6);
          30*z(3)-40*z(5)];

tspan=[0,200];
Z0=[0.05 0.04 0.03];
[t,z] = ode45('exh',tspan,Z0);
plot(t,z)
```

Comment: Can you describe what's not working in a bit more detail?

Comment: it gives me an error

Comment: Error in odearguments (line 87)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 113)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your system has dimension 6, your initial value has dimension 3, this can not work, the dimensions have to be the same.

In other words, you need not only the initial positions but also the initial velocities for a system of order 2.